# Pesquisa filtrada (por Label blogger)

Tags: javascript, html, xml, algoritmo-de-busca, blogger

Olá, estou tendo Problema em um sistema de busca blogger. O problema é que eu quero filtra as pesquisas por *Label*.

```html
<form action='/search' class='navbar-form navbar-right' id='searchthis' method='get' role='search' style='display: inline;'>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <input class='form-control' name='q' placeholder='Search' type='text' />
    <input>
    <b:loop values='data:posts' var='searh'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.search == data:blog.homepageUrl'>
    <b:if cond='data:post.labels'>
    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label' type='hidden'>
    <b:if cond='data:label.name == "Todos os episódios"'>
    <b:include data='search' name='printPosts'/>
    </b:if>
    </b:loop>
    </b:if>
    <b:else/>
    <b:include data='search' name='printPosts'/>
    </b:if>
    </b:loop>
  </div>
  <button class='btn btn-danger' type='submit'><span aria-hidden='true' class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'/></button>
</form>
```

Fiz vários testes mas ainda assim não funciona a filtragem de poster.

P.S.: não entendo muito linguagem de *HTML* dai os scripts podem está meio loucos

Comment: Dê mais detalhes do que você está tentando fazer.